# SmartGWT close/hide all windows

Tags: gwt, window, smartgwt

How can I close/hide/iterate through all SmartGWT or GWT Windows?

For example:

```
Set<Window> allWindow = SecretGWTClass.getAllWindows();
for(Window w : allWindow)
   w.hide();
```

Comment: What do you mean with hide a Window? Minimize the browser window? Something like this you can't do. Look at the api of the Window class http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/Window.html